# how to set my system service permission?

Tags: android, service, permissions, system

I create a service and add into the SystemService.
But I find my service can't optate extsd card as the it's the permission of WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
I had read the file:
http://www.chainfire.eu/articles/113/Is_Google_blocking_apps_writing_to_SD_cards_/
And know how to add the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in my system.
but it's not work.emphasized text

I write the test code in app, it's ok, and I check the permission is right as the below:

```
File newDir = new File("/mnt/extsd/");
newDir.mkdirs();
File wtSd = new File(newDir.getAbsolutePath(), "file.txt");
BufferedWriter writer;

try {
    java.lang.Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("id");
    InputStream input = process.getInputStream();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1204];
    int len;
    while((len = (input.read(bytes))) > 0){
        System.out.print(new String(bytes, 0, len));
    }
    input.close();
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Log.i(TAG, "write extsd"+wtSd.getAbsolutePath()+wtSd.getName());
try {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(wtSd));
    writer.write("hello, extsd");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

the permission is :
I/System.out( 2804): uid=10036(app_36) gid=10036(app_36) groups=1000(system),1015(sdcard_rw)
I/AR300 UPD( 2804): write extsd/mnt/extsd/file.txtfile.txt

---

but at the same code in system service, it's bad

### the code is

```
try{
    java.lang.Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("id");
    InputStream input = process.getInputStream();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1204];
    int len;
    while((len = (input.read(bytes))) > 0) {
        System.out.print(new String(bytes, 0, len));
    }
    input.close();
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

File newDir = new File("/mnt/extsd/");
newDir.mkdirs();
File wtSd = new File(newDir.getAbsolutePath(), "file.txt");
BufferedWriter writer;

Log.i(TAGC, "write extsd"+wtSd.getAbsolutePath());
try {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(wtSd));
    writer.write("hello, extsd");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

my service permission is:
I/System.out( 2249): uid=1000(system) gid=1000(system) groups=1001(radio),1002(bluetooth),1003(graphics),1004(input),1005(audio),1006(camera),1007(log),1008(compass),1009(mount),1010(wifi),1018(usb),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats),3007(net_bw_acct)

it's clear explain, my service can't opt 1015(sdcard_rw)

---

> drwxr-xr-x root     system            1970-01-02 03:17 asec d---rwxr-x
>   system   sdcard_rw          1970-01-01 00:00 extsd drwxr-xr-x root
>   system            1970-01-02 03:17 obb drwx------ root     root
>   1970-01-02 03:17 secure drwxrwxr-x system   graphics
>   1970-01-02 03:17 shm d--------- system   system            1970-01-02
>   03:17 udisk

---

mount

> root@android:/mnt # mount rootfs / rootfs ro,relatime 0 0 tmpfs /dev
>   tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0 devpts /dev/pts devpts
>   rw,relatime,mode=600 0 0 proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0 sysfs /sys
>   sysfs rw,relatime 0 0 none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0 tmpfs
>   /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0 tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs
>   rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0 tmpfs /mnt/shm tmpfs
>   rw,relatime,size=1024k,mode=775,uid=1000,gid=1003 0 0 none /dev/cpuctl
>   cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0 /dev/block/mmcblk0p5 /system ext4
>   ro,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0 /dev/block/mmcblk0p7
>   /data ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,errors=panic,user_xattr,barrier=0,nomblk_io_submit,data=ordered,noauto_da_alloc,discard 0 0 /dev/block/mmcblk0p6 /cache ext4
>   rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
>   /dev/block/mmcblk0p8 /vendor ext4
>   rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0 none
>   /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
>   **/dev/block/vold/179:25 /mnt/extsd vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro
>   0 0**

---

how to add the 1015 group in system??

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem. You should add necessary groups in the `--setgroups` option when starting `SystemServer` in the `ZygoteInit`.